# Can anyone explain Swift Combine's Subject.eraseToAnySubject() method and where it should be used?

Tags: swift, combine

I can see that `Subject.eraseToAnySubject()` returns the concrete `Subject` type `AnySubject`. I'm assuming this is using a type eraser pattern.

However, the apple docs provide almost no details: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/passthroughsubject/3241547-erasetoanysubject

Can anyone explain how this works and where it should be used?

Also, would it be possible to use the `some` keyword to avoid using `AnySubject`?

Comment: Check out https://medium.com/@chris_dus/type-erasure-in-swift-84480c807534

Answer (score 18):

In Combine, as you chain Publishers to Operators, the return type becomes complicated very quickly since it includes specific detail about each publisher in the chain.

For example a simple string Publisher with a filter and map Operator attached will have a return type of: `<Filter<Map<Published<String, Error>>>>`

`eraseToAny` uses a type eraser pattern to capture what's actually important about the return type. In the example given, adding an `eraseToAnyPublisher` will shorten the type to a more succinct `<AnyPublisher<String, Error>>`

Comment: beautifully explained!